# Machine learning: Training and Development Sets

Tags: machine-learning, svm, train

There are

- Training Set,
- Development Set (to tune the parameters)
- Test Set.

Is it possible to use **SVM** with the Training Set and various of features set, to get various of classifiers, and then test the classifiers on the Development Set, pick the classifier that gave the best result, and test it on the Test Set?

Is it the purpose of Development Set?